# Prevent React from importing CSS files that are not being used yet

Tags: css, reactjs

Concerning page loading speed, It seems strange to me that React is importing CSS files that are imported in components that are not even being used on the homepage. My react app seems to be importing every css file in my entire project, i'm sure this is affecting my page speed. How can i prevent react from importing css files (which are being imported by components) that are not even being imported/exist on a certain page?

For example my homepage may have Comp1.js, comp2.js and comp3.js and each of these files import their own css files. But i see css files from other pages being loaded in the html head tag...(see screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: It would aid the community in understanding your issue if you could share how you are bundling your app.

Comment: What do you mean bundling my app? You want to see my folder structure?

Comment: I mean do you have a custom build using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) or some other build tool?  Or are you using the default build from [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/)?  How are you styling your components?  Are you importing a CSS file into each of them?  Or are you using Sass, or styled components, or some other approach?  All this is necessary in understanding your particular scenario.

Comment: As i mentioned i am importing a css file into each jsx component. I am using create-react-app and using regular css to style my components.

Comment: Is this in your development environment?  This is typical when using CRA and webpack for dev; when you do a proper production build you would expect to see this optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const comp1 = await import('path');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, which led me to discover this question. Here's what worked for me:

Instead of importing the CSS files at the head of the component's source, you can import the file using `import(<path>);` in the `render()` function in case of class-based components, or before the `return()` statement in case of stateless functional components.

That way React won't be able to load the files at app's startup because their imports have been abstracted away by not being there in the top level structure of any component.

I'm just beginning to learn React so if anyone has a clearer explanation of how this works, I'll be more than happy to know.